# Searching on converting Julian dates in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, julian-date

I am pulling in invoice dates from a table in SQL Server 2008. The dates are in Julian.
I've converted them using:

```
CONVERT(char(12), dateadd(dd, (t2.date_paid - 639906), '1/1/1753'), 101)
```

Great. Now, when I attempt to limit results in the WHERE clause with

```
AND CONVERT(char(12), dateadd(dd, (t2.date_paid - 639906), '1/1/1753'), 101) 
  BETWEEN '07/01/2012' AND '07/31/2012'
```

I receive dates outside of that range. The `t2.date_paid` column will return dates from 2004.
Thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend to use a language-independent date format if you need to use strings to represent dates. That would be the **ISO-8601** format - in SQL Server that would be `YYYYMMDD` (**no dashes!**) - so in your case, use `.. BETWEEN '20120701' AND '20120731'` to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the date you create with `dateadd` to a string so you are doing a string comparison instead of a date comparison.

Comment: Thank you Mikael very much for your input.  First, I can avoid the issue by searching with the Julian date and the data pulls correctly with `and t2.date_paid between '734716' and '734746'`, this is more of a 'why' more than I can't get it fixed issue.  You're absolutely correct about using 'between'. However, the solution you provided pulled no results.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the answer leaving the part that answers the question "why".